# Override MFA for a Google IDP provider in firebase authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication, google-identity, idp

I am using firebase authentication for login. Multiple login providers enabled. Means i can login via username and password, gooogle and microsoft idp also. I have enrolled the MFA using sms also. I need to override the MFA sign in process for the google and microsoft provider login even if the MFA is enrolled when using the username and password login. Is it possible?

I searched a lot. Not yet get a solution for this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, both [SMS based MFA](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa) and [TOTP based MFA](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa) have no specific requirement on what the first sign-in provider is. Can you edit your question to show where you got stuck, or what error you get?